# Availability of Zinbardel wine

Tags: wine

Back in the 1960s and early 1970s I used to drink a jug wine called **Zinbardel**.  They stopped making it and I haven't been able to find it since. Does anyone still make **Zinbardel** wine?

Comment: Was this a red or white wine or did they produce both types of wine?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called "Zinbardel". The only thing close is Zinfandel. Just in case I was missing something I did a google search on ZinBARdel and it had only 6 results. One of them was your question! Now if you are talking about ZinFANdel, all you have to do is go to your closest supermarket and buy a jug of Gallo Zinfandel.

Comment: Google didn't exist inthe 60s and 70s, so I'm not particularly surprised you didn't find anything there.

Comment: I have 18 years in the wine industry and I have never heard of it. I did a search on it through the federal government at https://www.ttbonline.gov and they show no record of any product with that name.

Comment: I would have said what Steve S said.

Comment: @Xander Not really relevant: many other subjects with information of interest published prior to Google's existence have that information posted to the web and subsequently indexed by Google.

Comment: I am quite an expert in grape varieties. I checked my references, some of them quite old and could not find any reference. Grape varieties do not come and go that quickly. You be the judge. Zinfandel or Zinbardel?

Answer (score 1):

The marketing strategy of labeling wines below the luxury or super-premium price points with grape varietal names was just emerging in the late 60s or early 70s. So the product name may not have been a varietal; as a "jug wine" it may have been a marketing name for a blend (perhaps Zinfandel & Barbera).

Alternatively Hugh Johnson's Vintage: *The Story of Wine* states that a vine called '**Black Zinfardel** from Hungary' was offered in the 1830 catalog of the Princes of Long Island nursery (p 364). Could it be a memory lapse?

Comment: I thought the original poster was having a "lapse". I agree it could be Zinfardel. Zinbardel could be a mash up of zinfandel and barbera, but if it was a jug wine, there should be some record of it out there and I searched high and low and could find nothing.